# Daily builds of the Linux kernel with Launchpad

Tags: kernel, launchpad, daily-build

How can I create a PPA with a [source package recipe](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds) to build a patched Linux kernel that tracks the mainline Ubuntu kernel?

I'm struggling to even figure out which Launchpad project to build from.

[`lp:linux`](https://launchpad.net/linux) has only a `master` branch so I'm not sure how to build the code for a given Ubuntu release. (It seems to be identical to `lp:ubuntu/+source/linux`, but is it?) Compare to [`lp:ubuntu/+source/linux-meta`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta) which has branches like `applied/ubuntu/focal-security`.

There is [`lp:~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/focal`](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/focal) whose `master-prep` branch has tags that correspond with the package versions I see in the apt repositories, but I doubt I can construct a source package recipe that looks for new tags. (Also, the current tag is ahead of the latest released package version in the apt repos.)

However, the simplest recipe that uses this branch would be:

```
# git-build-recipe format 0.4 deb-version {debupstream}-0~{revtime}
lp:~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/focal master-prep
```

It [fails](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/672123357/buildlog.txt.gz) because the repository doesn't contain a `debian/control` file:

```
RUN ['git-build-recipe', '--safe', '--no-build', '--manifest', '/home/buildd/build-RECIPEBRANCHBUILD-3556697/chroot-autobuild/home/buildd/work/tree/manifest', '--distribution', 'focal', '--allow-fallback-to-native', '--append-version', '~ubuntu20.04.1', '/home/buildd/build-RECIPEBRANCHBUILD-3556697/chroot-autobuild/home/buildd/work/recipe', '/home/buildd/build-RECIPEBRANCHBUILD-3556697/chroot-autobuild/home/buildd/work/tree']
...
git-build-recipe: error: No control file to take the package name from, and --package not specified.
```

When building manually, according to the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel), you need to run `LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules clean` to generate `debian/control`. But Launchpad won't let me use the `run` command in my recipe to invoke this.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question but you can install the latest mainline kernel with this tool https://github.com/bkw777/mainline